# Is LVM mirroring supported on RHEL 5?

Tags: lvm

We have SW MD RAID1 on a RHEL5. RAID devices come from multipath currently.

**Question**: Is it possible to "convert" this setup to LVM mirroring? Does RHEL 5 supports mirroring in LVM? Just like in a RAID1? Or RAID1 like LVM mirroring is only from RHEL 6?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this?  For most situations MD RAIDs are preferable to LVM ones.

Comment: Yes, random crashes, because according to official RHEL support, it's not supported to use multipath+sw RAID1

Comment: Perhaps worth referencing your other (related) question you subsequently posted : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247411/how-to-convert-sw-md-raid1-arrays-to-lvm-mirrors "How to convert SW MD RAID1 arrays to LVM mirrors?"

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an answer, but it is a suggestion:

According to Red Hat, RHEL 5 is in "Production Phase 3" where only "Critical Impact Security" and "Critical Impact Bug" fixes are being pushed and it goes out of general support on March 31, 2017. That's 15 months. I've worked places where that was an entire procurement cycle.

I realize (having worked in these sorts of environments) that it is not always possible to do a reinstall, but if your time and data are valuable I would REALLY suggest spending the time to get up to speed with RHEL 7, get a second machine up and running and configured right, then migrate your data over. This will let you re-plan your disk subsystems and get everything arranged right.

I would have put this as a comment, but it was too long. Sorry.