# How to convert SW MD RAID1 arrays to LVM mirrors?

Tags: lvm, raid1

We have SW MD RAID1 on a RHEL5. RAID devices come from multipath currently.

```
# pvs -v --segments
    Scanning for physical volume names
  PV                              VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start SSize  LV                 Start Type   PE Ranges                              
  /dev/md0                        foovg    lvm2 a--   20.00G      0      0   5119 barrootlv              0 linear /dev/md0:0-5118                        
  /dev/md1                        foovg    lvm2 a--   20.00G  20.00G     0   5119                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md12                       foovg2   lvm2 a--   32.00G      0      0   8191 baru03db2lv            0 linear /dev/md12:0-8190                       
  /dev/md13                       foovg2   lvm2 a--   32.00G  15.99G     0   4097 baru03db2lv         8191 linear /dev/md13:0-4096                       
  /dev/md13                       foovg2   lvm2 a--   32.00G  15.99G  4097   4094                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md14                       foobarvg2 lvm2 a--   32.00G   7.00G     0   6400 baru06foobarelv        0 linear /dev/md14:0-6399                       
  /dev/md14                       foobarvg2 lvm2 a--   32.00G   7.00G  6400   1791                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md15                       foobarvg2 lvm2 a--   32.00G  32.00G     0   8191                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md2                        foovg    lvm2 a--   20.00G  20.00G     0   5119                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md24                       foovg5   lvm2 a--   32.00G   6.99G     0   5120 baru10db5lv            0 linear /dev/md24:0-5119                       
  /dev/md24                       foovg5   lvm2 a--   32.00G   6.99G  5120      2 baru10eprinttlv    24574 linear /dev/md24:5120-5121                    
  /dev/md24                       foovg5   lvm2 a--   32.00G   6.99G  5122   1280 baru10db5lv         5120 linear /dev/md24:5122-6401                    
  /dev/md24                       foovg5   lvm2 a--   32.00G   6.99G  6402   1789                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md27                       foobarvg5 lvm2 a--   64.00G  13.99G     0  12800 baru010archlv          0 linear /dev/md27:0-12799                      
  /dev/md27                       foobarvg5 lvm2 a--   64.00G  13.99G 12800      1 baru10eprfoobarelv  8191 linear /dev/md27:12800-12800                  
  /dev/md27                       foobarvg5 lvm2 a--   64.00G  13.99G 12801   3582                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md28                       foovg6   lvm2 a--  128.00G      0      0  32767 baru11db6lv            0 linear /dev/md28:0-32766                      
  /dev/md29                       foovg6   lvm2 a--   64.00G   1.99G     0  15873 baru11db6lv        32767 linear /dev/md29:0-15872                      
  /dev/md29                       foovg6   lvm2 a--   64.00G   1.99G 15873    510                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md30                       foobarvg6 lvm2 a--   32.00G      0      0   8191 baru011archlv          0 linear /dev/md30:0-8190                       
  /dev/md31                       foobarvg6 lvm2 a--    8.00G      0      0   2047 baru011archlv       8191 linear /dev/md31:0-2046                       
  /dev/md5                        foovg    lvm2 a--   20.00G  20.00G     0   5119                        0 free                                          
  /dev/md6                        foovg    lvm2 a--   80.00G  80.00G     0  20479                        0 free
```

**Question**: (just one example would be enough) how can we convert these devices to LVM mirrors online? To reach the same functionality, as with RAID1.

Assumption (but how*? and is it OK? will there be enough space?):

```
1. - disassemble one side of the given RAID1 device. 
2. - put the disk/partition of the disassembled RAID1 device to the given VG. 
3. - move the segments of the remaining side of the given RAID1 to the newly (one of the old side of the raid1) added disk in the VG. 
4. - remove the last remaining side in the given raid1 and put it in the VG as mirror.
```

*what are the commands?

Comment: Remember Lt. Murphy in your plans: 

0) Back up all the data. 
...
5) realize that in step one you grabbed a few extra devices, or the wrong set of devices.
6) blow it all away and start from scratch. Oh, you DID validate your backups first, right?

Comment: Your assumption is about right. The wonderful thing about mirroring storage systems that can operate in degraded mode is that moving between them is comparatively painless. Backups, though, are a must.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  The specific commands are:

1) `mdadm -fr /dev/mdxx /dev/sdXX`
2) `pvcreate /dev/sdXX` and `vgextend vgname /dev/sdXX`
3) `pvmove /dev/mdxx`
4) `mdadm --stop /dev/mdxx` and `pvcreate /dev/sdXX` ( the *other* drive ) and `vgextend vgname /dev/sdXX`, and finally `lvconvert -m 1 vg/lv` for each lv you want mirrored.